Install a Private Github Release (Python)
I have this problem where no matter what I try to do it always returns the 404 error, the file path is correct, the token is correct and has all the permissions but it still won't work.
import requests
import os

def download_file(url, file_path, headers):
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
        print(f"Success: {file_path}")
    else:
        print(f"Status code: {response.status_code}")

def main():
    url = "https://github.com/whoisttg/deploy/releases/download/0.0.1/test.exe"
    file_name = "test.exe"
    download_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "downloads")
    os.makedirs(download_dir, exist_ok=True)
    file_path = os.path.join(download_dir, file_name)
    
    headers = {"Authorization": "token <my token>"}
    
    download_file(url, file_path, headers)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I tried using a normal github link and an api one.

A 404 error is an HTTP status code that indicates that the server could not find the requested web page or resource. When you visit a website and encounter a 404 error, it means that the server cannot locate the specific URL you're trying to access.
